# Get image inside a post using wp_get_recent_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a a page in wordpress where I show 5 recent posts.
I was able to successfully do that.

However, I am not able to retrieve images that are present inside that post.

I am using this code to retrieve post url and post image. (Post URL works fine!)

```
$args = array('numberposts'=>'5');
$recentposts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);  
foreach($recentposts as $post){
    $v = $post['ID'];
    $postlink = get_permalink($v);
    $postimg = get_the_post_thumbnail($v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```html
$posts = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
foreach ( $posts as $_post ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```